# com.couchbase.lite.CouchbaseLiteException when document.putProperties(map) is called - Android?

Tags: android, json, gson, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I am trying to save a new Document in CouchbaseLite but facing this issue, getting exception.

```
com.couchbase.lite.CouchbaseLiteException
```

**Exception Message:**

```
com.couchbase.lite.CouchbaseLiteException
com.couchbase.lite.CouchbaseLiteException
null
[1462915328, 451, 1462915272, 5, 1463020336, 137, 1463020280, 9, 1462744624, 39,        1462943280, 4, 1463283568, 58, 1463284808, 9, 1459791184, 28, 1463191704, 0, 1463287160, 0, 1463294584, 8, 1463285984, 2, 1463298952, 2, 1461828864, 24, 1459658792, 6, 1461922408, 22, 1459660472, 15, 1461916072, 3, 1461898944, 8, 1459489944, 18, 1459609664, 2, 1459600392, 2, 1459600456, 4, 1460186072, 84, 1460049056, 48, 1459080768, 0, 1459081896, 17, 1460208056, 11, 1460002968, 66, 1459100640, 0]
null
Status: 400
[]
```

Thought the exception is not clear that what is happening behind, I do not know what to do, what to interpret from it.

**Here is my code:**

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map = (Map<String, Object>) gson.fromJson(json, map.getClass());
    //map.put("_id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());

    Document document = mDatabaseLocal.createDocument();

    try {
        document.putProperties(map);
    } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*After making a lot of research on this:*

I found that you should not have any property in your map which has a key starting with **underscore character** `'_'` because it is reserved for `CouchbaseLite`.

CouchbaseLite currently does not give you a proper exception message for this so you will be stuck. The only thing you need to take care is to not to include any such key in your map.

Like if you have _id and _rev fields in your class(obj) then you need to remove them

```
map.remove("_id");
map.remove("_rev");
```

before calling:

```
try {
        document.putProperties(map);
    } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: True, _ are special members: they are from meta ( Any keys in the dictionary that begin with "_", such as "_id" and "_rev", contain CouchbaseLite metadata). But in terms of advised to remove them, it's the opposite, from documentation for putProperties: The properties dictionary must have a "_rev" property whose ID matches the current revision's (as it will if it's a modified copy of this document's .properties property.). What's not clear is what it should be with new doc (currentRevision is null)